# Detect javascript settings in browser

Tags: javascript

My requirement is that I have to check if the javascript is enabled or disabled in the browser. Because i am working on DOJO, if the javascript is disabled, application will not be running. If the javascript is disabled, i have to prompt the user to enable the javascript. Can anyone help me to find the way i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `noscript` tag.

```
<noscript>Your need to enable javascript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [noscript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/noscript) element.

> The noscript element represents nothing if scripting is enabled, and represents its children if scripting is disabled. ***It is used to present different markup to user agents that support scripting and those that don't support scripting***, by affecting how the document is parsed.

The best practice is to [gracefully degrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Degrading_gracefully), though.